# MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 in grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
    protected void LinkButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          String MyConnection2 = "Server=localhost;database=ovs;Uid=root;password=; Convert Zero Datetime=True";
        MySqlConnection MyConn2 = new MySqlConnection(MyConnection2);
        GridViewRow grdrow = (GridViewRow)((LinkButton)sender).NamingContainer;
        string firstColData = grdrow.Cells[0].Text;
        String query= "insert into Voting (studentID)values (" + firstColData + ")";
        MySqlCommand MyCommand2 = new MySqlCommand(query, MyConn2);
        MySqlDataReader MyReader2;
        MyConn2.Open();
        MyReader2 = MyCommand2.ExecuteReader();

        while (MyReader2.Read())
        {
        }
        MyConn2.Close();

     

    }
      

    }
protected void loadCandidate()
    {
        con.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select studentID, name from candidate where faculty='FOCS'", con);
        MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.HasRows == true)
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = dr;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

The load candidate is select the candidate inforation to be display in the gridview and there is  button call vote, the
studentID and name will be insert to another table called Voting.But now, i click the vote button, the studentID and name is not being inserted in the Voting table. There is an error message MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'Column count doesn't match value count at row 1'There is 2 things i store in voting, one is voterID(auto incress), the others is studentID.

Comment: Can you share the code which inserts the data for voting?

Comment: hello, the code for insert into the Voting will be ` string command = "insert into Voting values ('" + firstColData + "')";`. The intention is to store the data that being display in the gridview which is the studentID and the name in the Voting table.

Comment: What's the issue you are facing? you are creating command but not executing. You need to execute the command against the database to insert the database.

Comment: Hello, I having some questions.My intention is when the user click the button, it will get the studentID and name from the gridview and then insert it to the Voting table. I'm a bit confuse about the executing part. I though i already execute the insert command in `string command = "insert into Voting values ('" + firstColData + "')";`.By the string command, i expect the data in grdrow.Cells[0].Text to be inseted to the Voting table

Comment: You are using `MySqlCommand` and executing it to select data from the database in `loadCandidate` method. You need to do similar to insert the data to.. I suggest to read more about database operation to MySQL from C# to get hold of it. If you want user to click button then you should have button and event handler for handling button's click event and you need to write code in the eventhandler. It is not clear what's the issue you are facing. the code is incomplete so it is difficult to suggest any concrete solution.

Comment: Hello, when i click the vote button, there is an error message MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'Column count doesn't match value count at row 1'

Answer (score 0):

here is a example how to write data in ado.net DB:

```
using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=MSDataShape;Data Provider=SQLOLEDB;" +  
  "Data Source=(local);Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=northwind"))  
{  
OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SHAPE {SELECT CustomerID, CompanyName FROM Customers} " +  
  "APPEND ({SELECT CustomerID, OrderID FROM Orders} AS Orders " +  
  "RELATE CustomerID TO CustomerID)", connection);  
  
DataSet customers = new DataSet();  
adapter.Fill(customers, "Customers");  
}
```

Here you can fill the customer-object with your data. It will be written if you close the connection, after the last bracket. Keep in mind that the modification only will be written to the database if you close the connection. using (dbconnection) {} closes it automatically.

refer to your question you can also do the following:

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
  candidate["name"] = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text;
}
```

Comment: Hello, which mean i should do it at the GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged1 funtion?